# Absolute Text position in PDF generated by Matplotlib (figimage for text?)

Tags: matplotlib

Am trying to use Matplotlib for pretty formal PDF output and thus need to cleanly add the page number to the bottom of every page.
Unfortunately I cannot figure out how to make it independently of the figure size. My pages all have the same width but different heights and I'd like the text to be e.g. 30 pixels abvoe the bottomline of the page.

What I tried is:

```
    y = 0.05 * fig.get_size_inches()[1]
    fig.text(0.1, yy, str(n+1), ha='center', fontsize=8)

    self.pdf.savefig(fig)
```

Where fig is my current figure.
This results in a text position

To add the company logo and other visual deocrations, I successfully use figimage which has the xo and yo paramters. Those are in absolute pixels.
Unfortunately the supposed equivalent "figtext" does not have them.

Is there a solution for this issue?
Huge thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the method I tried does work. I just had to manually add the padding ("pad" which I'm adding to tight_layout) since that comes ontop of the figure size, when the PDF page is generated.